# Validating public method arguments

Tags: c#

I'm not sure how to properly handle argument validation in public methods when these methods overload/invoke other public methods.

For example:

```
class Example
{
    public bool Has(string key)
    {
        if (key == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(key));

        return false;
    }

    public object Get(string key)
    {
        // Should I check if key is null here?
        if (!Has(key))
            throw new ArgumentException("No key exists", nameof(key));

        return null;
    }
}
```

This is obviously a simple example, but what is the preferred way to deal with this, especially considering multiple arguments that might end up invoking several publicly visible methods?

Should I throw exceptions/validate arguments on each individual method (which leads to a lot of duplication/checking the same condition several times) or is it acceptable to delegate the checking to other methods (in this example let the 'Has' method check if the key is valid and don't do so in the 'Get' method).

Comment: I think this question is more suited for the [programmers SE](https://programmers.stackexchange.com/) site and should be *migrated*, specifically because the code is working fine AFAIK.

Comment: Have you tried looking at this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13042975/exception-handling-practices-top-level-vs-every-function)?

Comment: @nick-s My question is about throwing exceptions, not catching them thus your link doesn't really help me. I'm mostly trying to avoid a lot of code duplication/checking the same argument several times.

Comment: @Slay3R if i were you, i would log the message that the parameter is null in Has() method and throw the exception in Get() method after the check. I think it is mostly design system that you follow. It is quite similar to exception catching question in the link that i provided.

Comment: @ray when referring other sites, it is often helpful to point that [cross-posting is frowned upon](http://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/cross-posting/info)

Comment: @gnat: That's why I said that the question should be *migrated* (i.e. moved, *not* re-posted/duplicated).

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to throw an Exception on each method. The exception throwed on your "Has" method will propagate into the stack to the "Get" method, so it's fine if you handle validations at one single point. However, I suggest you to check if throwing exceptions is the best method that fit your needs, or if you could handle it in another way.